# Limit of arithmetic mean of series of measurements

Tags: limits, probability-theory, physics, means

Assume we have a series of measurements $x_i$ of, say, some physical quantity with (unknown) real value $x_r$. In a physics book I found the statement that, if we could exclude systematic errors in our measurement, we have
\begin{equation}
(1)\quad x_r=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i.
\end{equation}
There is also some kind of "proof", starting with definitions
\begin{equation}
\bar{x}_n:=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i,\quad
e_i:=x_r-x_i,\quad
\varepsilon:=x_r-\bar{x},
\end{equation}
that is,
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n(x_r-x_i)=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n e_i.
\end{equation}

Next step is the calculation
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_i e_i\right)^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i e_i^2+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i\sum_{j\neq i}e_ie_j\approx\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i e_i^2
\end{equation}
for $n\to\infty$, using that $e_i$ and $e_j$ are statistically independent. **I can make no sense of this conclusion, and then, how does this yield the above statement (1)?**

Comment: This is basically data reconciliation. Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304612/standard-deviation-for-a-reconciled-value which is a question of mine. May be, it could help.

Comment: This is essentially an attempt at the [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks an awful lot like the [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) to me.

I'll assume that each of the measurements are independent, identically distributed and (as you say that we can "exclude systematic errors"), each has a mean of $x_r$. So $E(x_i)=x_r$ for each $i$, $E(e_i)=x_r-E(x_i)=0$ for each $i$, and $E(\bar{x}_n)=E\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i{x_i} \right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_iE(x_i)=x_r$ for all $n$.

I'll also edit your book's notation a little: I'll use $\varepsilon_n:=x_r-\bar{x}_n$ instead of just $\varepsilon$ as it seems that the book's use of $\varepsilon$ still depends on $n$.

We have that $E(\varepsilon_n)=x_r-E(\bar{x}_n)=0$ for all $n$. Because of this, $$\mathrm{Var}(\varepsilon_n)=E(\varepsilon_n^2)-E(\varepsilon_n)^2=E(\varepsilon_n^2)-0=E(\varepsilon_n^2)$$
... so your final line of working suggests that the book wants to be working with the variance of $\varepsilon_n$.

Furthermore, if the $x_i$ are independent, then the $e_i$ are also independent, which means that their covariances are zero. So, for all $i\neq j$:
$$0=\mathrm{Cov}(e_i,e_j)=E(e_ie_j)-E(e_i)E(e_j)=E(e_ie_j)-0=E(e_ie_j)$$
... which suggests why the book ignores the $\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i\sum_{j\neq i}e_ie_j$ term.

Putting all of this together (and finding the epectation of your final line of working) we get:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}(\varepsilon_n) &= E(\varepsilon_n^2)
\\ &= \ldots 
\\ &= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i E(e_i^2)
\\ &= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i \mathrm{Var}(e_i)
\\ &= \frac{1}{n^2}\times n \times \mathrm{Var}(e_1)
\\ &= \frac{1}{n} \mathrm{Var}(e_1)
\end{align}$$
 where we've used the fact that if the $e_i$ are identically distributed then they all have the same variance.

Intuitively now, you can see that if $n$ gets large then the variance of your error term $\varepsilon_n$ becomes small. More rigorously, we could use [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Proof_using_Chebyshev's_inequality_assuming_finite_variance) to show that $\varepsilon_n$ converges in probability to zero and hence that $\bar{x}_n$ converges in probability to $x_r$ (your statement (1)).